# Setting a listadapter in a fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a fragment Tab1Fragment which extends the Fragment class (so I can't extend the ListActivity, which is required for calling the setListAdapter method). In this fragment, I want to display a listview populated with custom objects.

Is there a way, I could set the adapter without changing the extended class to ListFragment? The problem is with the setListAdapter methods (marked with # HERE).

Here is the fragment code:

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<MobileNETDistinctChatInfo> m_parts = new ArrayList<MobileNETDistinctChatInfo>();
    private Runnable viewParts;
    private MobileNETDistinctChatInfoAdapter m_adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        MobileNETDBHandler db = new MobileNETDBHandler(getActivity());

        // instantiate Adapter class
        m_adapter = new MobileNETDistinctChatInfoAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.chatlist_list_item, m_parts);

        setListAdapter(m_adapter); # HERE

        // Thread, which fetches data in the background
        viewParts = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    };

    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewParts, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();
    return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
}


private Handler handler = new Handler()
 {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        m_parts.add(new MobileNETDistinctChatInfo("someone@gmail.com","Message1", "2013-01-01 11:11:11"));
        m_parts.add(new MobileNETDistinctChatInfo("someonelse@gmail.com","Message2", "2013-01-01 11:11:11"));
        m_parts.add(new MobileNETDistinctChatInfo("someonelselse@gmail.com","Message3", "2013-01-01 11:11:11"));

        m_adapter = new MobileNETDistinctChatInfoAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.chatlist_list_item, m_parts);

        // display the list.
        setListAdapter(m_adapter); # HERE
    }
};

}
```

I can't use the ListFragment, because of a method in another class, which returns tabs (they are named Tab1Fragment, Ta2Fragment,Tab3Fragment and extend the Fragment class), which is of the type Fragment, so I shouldn't extend ListFragment.

The method:

```
@Override  
public Fragment getItem(int position) {  

    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();  
    switch (position) {  
        case 0:  
            return fragment =  new Tab1Fragment();  
        case 1:  
            return fragment =  new Tab2Fragment();  
        case 2:  
            return fragment =  new Tab3Fragment();   
        default:  
            break;  
    }

    return fragment;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use ListFragment?

Comment: You can not extend "ListActivity" that is true. But you can definitely extend "ListFragment".

Comment: I tried extending ListFragment, but then there is the problem with the method getItem() (see above) which returns an object of the type Fragment. Since Tab1Fragment would extend ListFragment (which, in turn, extends Fragment) the method would not see it as an object of the type Fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `ListView` to layout `tab1.xml` and give id to this list. for example: `my_list`
2. update `onCreateView()` method in `Tab1Fragment` to be:

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
       ListView list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_list);

       MobileNETDBHandler db = new MobileNETDBHandler(getActivity());

       // instantiate Adapter class
       m_adapter = new MobileNETDistinctChatInfoAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.chatlist_list_item, m_parts);

       list.setListAdapter(m_adapter); # HERE

       // Thread, which fetches data in the background    
       viewParts = new Runnable(){
           public void run(){
               handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
           }
       };

       Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewParts, "MagentoBackground");
       thread.start();
       return view;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get a reference to the ListView object to be populated.
Having a look at your code, i believe it is defined in the LinearLayout you're inflating, so just do

```
LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
ListView list = (ListView) l.findViewById(R.id.my_listview_id);
list.setAdapter(m_adapter);
```

You can store the list view in a field if you'd like to make modifications later.

Answer (score 0):

Use like

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends ListFragment {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom list view class by extending BaseAdapter without changing any extended class in android. 
Here is sample code for this:

```
public class Simple_Fragment extends Fragment 
{


   class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  // here you adpter methods and impelement what do you want

        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your activity to `ListFragment` and this will work same as `ListActivity`.

Or you have to set your list adapter like this :

```
ListView mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.Id.your_list_view);
```

**To set list adapter**

```
mListView.setAdapter(YOUR_LIST_ADAPTER);
```